# Cleaner way to access consistently named nested json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a jsonb data structure on one of my models that always has two keys (ground and naval) with the attached unit data. example:

```rb
{
  "ground" => {
    "infantry" => 1, "artillery" => 1
  }, 
  "naval" => {
    "battleships" => 1, "carriers" => 1
  }
}
```

Many of the methods I am creating consistently need to access the underlying unit data so I end up having a lot of methods with the double nested loop like:

```rb
new_units.each do |battle_type, _value|
  new_units[battle_type].each do |type, quantity|
    damaged_unit_quantity += HEALING_TICK_RATE * healing_ticks
    new_units[battle_type][type] = quantity.floor + [damaged_unit_quantity, 1].min
  end
end
```

`HEALING_TICK_RATE`, `healing_ticks` and `damaged_unit_quantity` are floats

Is there a more readable way to avoid a double nested loop when needing to access/modify both the naval and ground units?

Comment: Quick note: `new_units[battle_type]` makes no sense when you could just use `_values` (they are the same object). While I have no idea what `damaged_unit_quantity`, `HEALING_TICK_RATE`, or `healing_ticks` are, it seems like you could use `new_units.values.transform_values {|quantity| quantity.floor + [damaged_unit_quantity  + (HEALING_TICK_RATE * healing_ticks), 1].min }`. This could likely be cleaned up further by understanding the currently unknown variables.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I used `new_units[battle_type]` because it felt more readable since I would use it again in the nested loop.

I updated the question to make the variables more clear.